# After editing .bashrc commands return 'command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH'

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I typed something in Bashrc and I can not use commands like `cp`, `gedit`, `ls`, etc. etc anymore.
The terminal give me a message like:

```
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
```

I tried to restore bashrc, but I need to use `cp` and I can not use this command either:

```
Command 'cp' is available in '/bin/cp'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
cp: command not found
```

What could I do? Thank you.

Comment: what if you use the full path for cp executable `/bin/cp`?

Comment: Please don't use an ALL-CAPS title.

Comment: "What could I do?"  "because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable"  add /bin to your PATH and use @bistoco hint. You need to fix the bashrc you edited ;-)

Comment: I've solve this issue by following way : Check here... https://askubuntu.com/a/1318368/1185282

Answer (score 30):

It looks like your `PATH` variable got messed up.

If this ever happens to you, and you are running a `/bin/sh` (or variant such as /bin/bash)....enter the following on the command line:

```
 export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

Then you will be able to easily use the base UNIX commands without having to prefix them with /....blah..../command while you are fixing the problem.

Comment: I've run this command and without rebooting the path variables got lost again without editing the bashrc again. Am I doomed into having to constantly update path in .bashrc whenever installing new software?

Comment: @janat08 it might be something in your bashrc that is causing the issue. I removed a export PATH line I had and it fixed the issue (I had added that line earlier).